# namespace of page which called this method

Tags: c#, asp.net

this code gives me Extentions namespace but I need aspx page namespace, how do I reach that? or I can use basepage for this method if better.

CLASS LIBRARY >

```
public static class Extentions
{
    public static string LANG(string text)
    {
        Type type = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType;
        string ns = type.Namespace.Replace(".", "_");
        return (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("language", ns + "_" + text);
    }
}
```

IN SOME ASPX PAGE >

```
<%=Extentions.LANG("Header")%>
```

This works for my specific problem ;

```
public string LANG(string text) 
{ 
    string ns = this.GetType().BaseType.FullName.Replace(".", "_"); 
    return (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("language", ns + "_" + text); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include a public property in your page like this:

```
public string PageNamespace
{
    get { return this.GetType().Namespace; }
}
```

Show this property in your page:

```
<%= PageNamespace %>
```

*NOTE: you can use this code: `this.GetType().Namespace` to get the page namespace inside of any page method which is not static. I gave this solution in my original answer, but it didn't work for the OP because he was trying to access it in an static method.*

Comment: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer

Comment: It's extremely strange that you cannot access this from your .aspx page. I do it all time. I've changed my answer, but the previous one should also work. Where is that code nested? Is must be inside some tag that make it behave strangely...

Comment: this one worked for me. I added at BasePage; I will accept your answer  because your answer help it to find this one; please edit with this so I ll accept for others.         public string LANG(string text)
        {
            string ns = this.GetType().BaseType.FullName.Replace(".", "_");
            return (string)HttpContext.GetGlobalResourceObject("language", ns + "_" + text);
        }

Comment: Your code doesn't return the page namespace. Mine does. Your code is solving a very particular problem of getting a resource with a name created from the base page full type name. Not gettint the page namespace. And, even if you didn't answer the question in the previous comment, I'm sure my first answer didn't work for you because you was tryign to access "this" in an static method. If you change your answer so that your solution makes sense, I'll of course change the answer. I think it's now useful for others as is.

Comment: Its ok if you say so, but your NameSpace return "ASP" always, don't know if its really useful for someone. thank you anyway

Comment: That's very starnge, please, see the namespace of your code behind. I've checked I get the correct namespace in which I declare my page. For example: `namespace H.WebApp.Pages.Accounting
{
    public partial class ExpensesPage : MyAppBasePage` gives me the correct `H.WebApp.Pages.Accounting` namespace. Please, look the code of your code behind page, and check the namespace... I bet it begins with `namespace ASP`. If not, I'd like to see the code to try to guess why is so for your particular case.

Comment: namespace Sxxxx.Web.Lxx.AxxxxxxCxxxxxx
{
    public partial class List : BasePage